# how to get tf-id from w2v on gensim

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, nlp, gensim, word2vec

I have a textual dataset on which I trained a `gensim` w2v model. Now I want to use those vectors to recive the tf-idf values for the words and documents in my data set. What is the right way to do it? I tried to followe the [tutorial](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/tut2.html) on gensim's site.

I expect something like `models.tfidfmodel(model.wv[model.wv.index2word])`
 but this fail since

`File "<ipython-input-229-7946418f8a82>", line 1, in <module>
    models.tfidfmodel(model.wv[model.wv.index2word])
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`

does what I want makes since? Is BOW the only way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tutorial you have linked to the model is given the corpus, i.e. the text (or transformed text) as a whole.

What you have **tried** to do is give the model the dictionary that the w2v model learned.

If what you want is

> to recive the tf-idf values for the words and documents in my data
>   set.

Then you should simply pass it as such:

```
tfidf = models.TfidfModel(corpus)
```

If what you actually want is to run the TF-IDF model on the *transformed* corpus, then you should first use your w2v to transform the corpus and then pass the transformed corpus to the tfidfmodel.

---

Note that as the tfidf model simply calculates the word frequency there is nothing to be gained by giving it the transformed corpus and not the original one.